# Windows tracert tool

Tags: windows, command-line, traceroute

Is there any information about packet loss in the tracert output ?

First column shows hop number and last column shows IPs, is other columns showing ping times ?

Answer (score 6):

You might be interested in the [`PathPing`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PathPing) tool distributed with Windows since Windows NT.

> PathPing is a network utility supplied
>   in Windows NT, Windows 2000, Windows
>   2003, Windows XP, Windows Vista and
>   Windows 7. It combines the
>   functionality of Ping with that of
>   Traceroute (in Windows: tracert), by
>   providing details of the path between
>   two hosts and Ping-like statistics for
>   each node in the path based on samples
>   taken over a time period, depending on
>   how many nodes are between the start
>   and end host. The advantages of
>   PathPing over ping and traceroute are
>   that each node is pinged as the result
>   of a single command, and that the
>   behavior of nodes is studied over an
>   extended time period, rather than the
>   Ping's default sample of four messages
>   or Traceroute's default single route
>   trace.

Comment: What the heck! I've never known about this. +

Comment: pathping is great for determining where problems actually exist in the network

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any information about packet
>   loss in the tracert output ?

Yes, packet loss is indicated by an asterisk instead of 'ping times'.

[image]

More info here:

**[Using Traceroute](http://networking.ringofsaturn.com/IP/traceroutedoc.php)** (scroll down to **Tracking Down Packet Loss**)

Comment: The link given is about traceroute, the unix-like version. The output is not exactly the same, as the pings are shown after the address.

Comment: the screenshot is taken from 'Windows' tracert, the asterisk remains. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can find a detailed information about tracert at [this link](http://www.hostingmanual.net/troubles/pr_traceroute.html).

Extract from the link answering your question:

> Traceroute is a tool that traces the
>   route that packets travel across a
>   network connection between two hosts.
>   The route between your computer and
>   your domain on our servers will vary
>   from time to time as the network
>   routers involved attempt to find the
>   fastest and most reliable route.
>
> The name (if available) and IP address
>   of each gateway (router) is displayed,
>   along with the round trip time (in
>   milliseconds) for each of three trace
>   packets to reach the specified gateway
>   and return. These intervals may vary
>   widely as a function of network load.
>   Lost packets are indicated by an
>   asterisk (*).

Answer (score 1):

[WinMTR](http://winmtr.sourceforge.net/) is well worth a look if you prefer GUIs.